# Rounding a decimal in Custom VB fraction code

Tags: reporting-services

I have created an SRSS report that shows height, width, and thickness which was in decimals and I have used custom VB code to convert those decimals to fractions. I am wondering if I can round those decimals in the Custom VB fraction code to get a smaller and appropriate fraction? Any suggestions?

```
Function GetFraction(ByVal Num As Double) As String
    If Num = 0# Then
        GetFraction = "None"
    Else
        Dim WholeNumber As Integer
        Dim DecimalNumber As Double
        Dim Numerator As Double
        Dim Denomenator As Double
        Dim a, b, t As Double
        WholeNumber = Fix(Num)
        DecimalNumber = Num - Fix(Num)
        Numerator = DecimalNumber * 10 ^ (Len(CStr(DecimalNumber)) - 2)
        Denomenator = 10 ^ (Len(CStr(DecimalNumber)) - 2)
        If Numerator = 0 Then
            GetFraction = WholeNumber
        Else
            a = Numerator
            b = Denomenator
            t = 0
            While b <> 0
                t = b
                b = a Mod b
                a = t
            End While
            If WholeNumber = 0 Then
                GetFraction = CStr(Numerator / a) & "/" & CStr(Denomenator / a)
            Else
                GetFraction = CStr(WholeNumber) & " " & CStr(Numerator / a) & "/" & CStr(Denomenator / a)
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean you'd like to round the decimal received by the function before the value is converted, you could add the built in `Round` function where ever `Num` is referenced.  The following can be used to transform the values -- the first parameter is the value you wish to round and the second specifies how many digits after the decimal point.

```
Decimal.Round(value,numbersRightOfDecimalPoint)
```

Since the values are `Double` datatypes, you will likely have to convert them to decimals with a `ToDecimal` function.  The `ToDecimal` function takes the value to convert and a regional culture, which we can just set to `Nothing` so it'll just round as normal.

```
Convert.ToDecimal(value, culture)
```

From what I can see, you should only need to modify these two lines where `Num` is referenced to round the value throughout the function.

```
 WholeNumber = Fix(Decimal.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(Num,Nothing), 2))
 DecimalNumber = Decimal.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(Num,Nothing),2) - Fix(Decimal.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(Num,Nothing),2))
```

Which yields a result like this:

> .501324532 >> 1/2

EDIT: On looking at your question again, it seems you MIGHT want to convert the decimals into fractions relating to measurements such as feet and inches.  For that, refer to [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c7c20e3c-b894-4c0b-8cf3-bca8df1de7b4/convert-decimal-value-to-feet-inches?forum=vbgeneral) which has additional functions you can implement for that requirement.