# Inserting a If then statement for custom VB code

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

I have queried a report that shows the width, height, and thickness of the windows which was in decimal format, until I inserted custom VB code in SSRS to change those decimals to fractions, And one particular fraction that suppose to say "5/23" is showing as "39/250" and I am wondering I can put a IF statement in to get 39/250 to say 5/23.

Fraction:

[image: FRaction]

```
Function GetFraction(ByVal Num As Double) As String
    If Num = 0# Then
        GetFraction = "None"
    Else
        Dim WholeNumber As Integer
        Dim DecimalNumber As Double
        Dim Numerator As Double
        Dim Denomenator As Double
        Dim a, b, t As Double

        WholeNumber = Fix(Decimal.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(Num,Nothing), 3))
        DecimalNumber = Decimal.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(Num,Nothing),3) - Fix(Decimal.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(Num,Nothing),3))
        Numerator = DecimalNumber *10 ^ (Len(CStr(DecimalNumber)) - 2)
        Denomenator = 10 ^ (Len(CStr(DecimalNumber)) - 2)
        If Numerator = 0 Then
            GetFraction = WholeNumber
        Else
            a = Numerator
            b = Denomenator
            t = 0

            While b <> 0
                t = b
                b = a Mod b
                a = t
            End While
            If WholeNumber = 0 Then
                GetFraction = CStr(Numerator / a) & "/" & CStr(Denomenator / a)
            Else
                GetFraction = CStr(WholeNumber) & " " & CStr(Numerator / a) & "/" & CStr(Denomenator / a)
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Seems like a precision problem, you should set all your variable to Decimal instead of Double.

Comment: I have done that, and I still have the same problem

Comment: Since you've applied my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54951807/10755978) but didn't [mark it as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to your previous problem, I'm not sure I want to help.  It'd be great if you use SO as it was intended, maybe you'd have more people willing to assist?  I'd say you probably want to use something like `IF GetFraction = "39/250"` but those fractions are actually completely different decimal values.  What decimal value is giving that fraction?

Comment: The decimal value of the 1563/10000 is 0.1563, but suppose to be 5/23. @Steve-o169

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you really want 5/32, not the 5/23 because 5/23 = 0.2173913043478261 while 5/32 = 0.15625 which seems to be the number you want.  What you need to do is adjust your rounding to five decimal points.  I believe these two lines just need the 3s switched to 5s.  It's possible you may need more like a 6 for this case, but since 5/32 has 5 digits right of the decimal point, I would guess this would fix your problem.

```
WholeNumber = Fix(Decimal.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(Num,Nothing), 5))
DecimalNumber = Decimal.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(Num,Nothing),5) - Fix(Decimal.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(Num,Nothing),5))
```